# Clustering COMET using Terracotta

Tags: java, jetty, comet, terracotta, cometd

We're trying to cluster a COMET web application written in Java using JETTY 7.0's implementation of suspended servlet 3.0 API.

Does anyone have experience using Terracotta in a suspend/resume servlet web application.

Greg Wilkins of JETTY mentions some issues with COMET performance with Terracotta.

- [Clustering COMETD with Terracotta](http://blogs.webtide.com/gregw/entry/clustering_cometd_with_terracotta)

Answer (score 1):

Another COMET clustering solution that actually uses COMETD internally to communicate amongst distributed nodes is called:

- [Oort Cloud discussions at COMETD Google Groups](http://groups.google.com/group/cometd-users/search?group=cometd-users&q=Oort&qt_g=Search+this+group)

  - You can try it by checking it out from the JETTY 7 SVN: http://svn.cometd.com/trunk/cometd-java/oort/